# Filter ListView with SearchView xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android

I want to filter Listview by Searchview

I use the following Adapter for the filter and it works if I haven't made any new additions to the adapter

When I add a new item to Listview, the search stops completely until I restart the program after adding, modifying or deleting it

full code

[adapter class](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fgnEdjJvikfLo-F_-JsaNjRpNDOp9tu5)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to achieve the result like following GIF?

[image]

If you want to add the item to the listview, based on your adapter, you should item in the adapter like following code.

```
   public class TableItemAdapter : BaseAdapter<TableItem>, IFilterable
    {
        public List<TableItem> _originalData;
        public List<TableItem> _items;
        private readonly Activity _context;


        public TableItemAdapter(Activity activity, IEnumerable<TableItem> tableitems)
        {

            _items = tableitems.ToList();
            _context = activity;

            Filter = new TableItemFilter(this);
        }

        //Add data to the `_items`, listview will be updated, if add data in the activity, 
        //there are two different lists, so listview will not update.
        public void AddData(TableItem tableItem)
        {
            _items.Add(tableItem);
            NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public override TableItem this[int position]
        {
            get { return _items[position]; }
        }

        public Filter Filter { get; private set; }

        public override int Count
        {
            get { return _items.Count; }
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }



        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var item = _items[position];

            View view = convertView;


            if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
                view = convertView ?? _context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.TableItem, null);
            //view = _context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.TableItem, null);
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text1).Text = item.Heading;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text2).Text = item.SubHeading;


            return view;

        }
        public override void NotifyDataSetChanged()
        {
           // this.NotifyDataSetChanged();
          base.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public class TableItemFilter :Filter
    {
        private readonly TableItemAdapter _adapter;
        public TableItemFilter(TableItemAdapter adapter)
        {
            _adapter = adapter;
        }

        protected override FilterResults PerformFiltering(ICharSequence constraint)
        {
            var returnObj = new FilterResults();
            var results = new List<TableItem>();


            if (_adapter._originalData == null)
                _adapter._originalData = _adapter._items;

            if (constraint == null) return returnObj;

            if (_adapter._originalData != null && _adapter._originalData.Any())
            {

                results.AddRange(
                    _adapter._originalData.Where(
                        item => item.SubHeading.ToLower().Contains(constraint.ToString()) | item.Heading.ToLower().Contains(constraint.ToString())));

            }


            returnObj.Values = FromArray(results.Select(r => r.ToJavaObject()).ToArray());
            returnObj.Count = results.Count;

            constraint.Dispose();

            return returnObj;
        }



        protected override void PublishResults(ICharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
        {
            using (var values = results.Values)
                _adapter._items = values.ToArray<Java.Lang.Object>().Select(r => r.ToNetObject<TableItem>()).ToList();

            _adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

            // Don't do this and see GREF counts rising
            constraint.Dispose();
            results.Dispose();
        }

    }

    public  class JavaHolder : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        public readonly object Instance;

        public JavaHolder(object instance)
        {
            Instance = instance;
        }


    }

    public static class ObjectExtensions
    {
        public static TObject ToNetObject<TObject>(this Java.Lang.Object value)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return default(TObject);

            if (!(value is JavaHolder))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to convert to .NET object. Only Java.Lang.Object created with .ToJavaObject() can be converted.");

            TObject returnVal;
            try { returnVal = (TObject)((JavaHolder)value).Instance; }
            finally { value.Dispose(); }
            return returnVal;
        }

        public static Java.Lang.Object ToJavaObject<TObject>(this TObject value)
        {
            if (Equals(value, default(TObject)) && !typeof(TObject).IsValueType)
                return null;

            var holder = new JavaHolder(value);

            return holder;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the activity, you add the data by adapter.

```
 private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            tableItemAdapter.AddData(new TableItem() { Heading = "test1222", SubHeading = "sub Test" });


        }
```

Here is my demo, you can download it.
https://github.com/851265601/Xamarin.Android_ListviewSelect/blob/master/XAListViewSearchDemo.zip

Comment: Are there any update for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the left upper corner), it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: Leon Lu thanks for replay I add the data through the sqLite rule not arraylist The problem is still present

Comment: Please share your data structure in sqlite table and share query code.