# filter listview with adapter using searchview xamarin.android

Tags: listview, xamarin.android, searchview

i'm creating an android app using Xamarin.android. my app has a customized listview that has 5 textviews in each row. I want to use a searchview to highlight the text in the textviews that have the same text as in the searchview or at least filter my listview according to my searchview text. I found this example: https://github.com/851265601/Xamarin.Android_ListviewSelect/blob/master/XAListViewSearchDemo.zip in this question [Filter ListView with SearchView xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61723948/filter-listview-with-searchview-xamarin) and tried to apply it. here is my code:

listview's adapter: homeadapter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.Lang;
namespace App36
{
    public class homeadapter : BaseAdapter<Rsultitem>, IFilterable
    {
       public List<Rsultitem> items;
       public List<Rsultitem> originaldata;
       public readonly Activity context;

        public homeadapter(Activity context, IEnumerable<Rsultitem> items)
            : base()
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.items = items.ToList();
            Filter = new TableItemFilter(this);
        }
        public void AddData(Rsultitem tableItem)
        {
            items.Add(tableItem);
            NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }
        public override Rsultitem this[int position]
        {
            get { return items[position]; }
        }
        public Filter Filter { get; private set; }
        public override int Count
        {
            get { return items.Count; }
        }
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var context = this.context;
            var item = items[position];
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create 
                view = convertView ?? context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.custom, null);
            //view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.custom, null);
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1).Text = item.itembarcode;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2).Text = item.name;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView3).Text = item.itemsunitcode;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView4).Text = item.currentQuantity;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView5).Text = item.moreInfo;
            //view.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.chbox).Checked=global.Exist;
            //var t = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView5);
            //t.Click +=delegate {
            //    Android.Widget.Toast.MakeText(context, t.Text, Android.Widget.ToastLength.Short).Show();
            //    //t.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Aqua);

            //};

           // view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.My_textView1).Text = items[position];

            TextView textView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView5);
            TextView textView1 = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
            TextView textView2 = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2);
            TextView textView3 = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView3);
            TextView textView4 = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView4);
            //textView.Text = items[position].ToString();
            // textView.Click += TextView_Click;


            if (!textView.HasOnClickListeners)
            {
                textView.Click += (o, e) =>
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(context, "click", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    context.StartActivity(typeof(Activity1));
                };
            }

           
            return view;
        }

        public override void NotifyDataSetChanged()
        {
            // this.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            base.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

    public class TableItemFilter : Filter
    {
        private readonly homeadapter _adapter;
        public TableItemFilter(homeadapter adapter)
        {
            _adapter = adapter;
        }

        protected override FilterResults PerformFiltering(ICharSequence constraint)
        {
            var returnObj = new FilterResults();
            var results = new List<Rsultitem>();


            if (_adapter.originaldata == null)
                _adapter.originaldata = _adapter.items;

            if (constraint == null) return returnObj;

            if (_adapter.originaldata != null && _adapter.originaldata.Any())
            {

                results.AddRange(
                    _adapter.originaldata.Where(
                        item => item.itembarcode.ToLower().Contains(constraint.ToString()) | item.itemsunitcode.ToLower().Contains(constraint.ToString())| item.name.ToLower().Contains(constraint.ToString())| item.currentQuantity.ToLower().Contains(constraint.ToString())));

            }


            returnObj.Values = FromArray(results.Select(r => r.ToJavaObject()).ToArray());
            returnObj.Count = results.Count;

            constraint.Dispose();

            return returnObj;
        }



        protected override void PublishResults(ICharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
        {
            using (var values = results.Values)
                _adapter.items = values.ToArray<Java.Lang.Object>().Select(r => r.ToNetObject<Rsultitem>()).ToList();

            _adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

            // Don't do this and see GREF counts rising
            constraint.Dispose();
            results.Dispose();
        }

    }

    public class JavaHolder : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        public readonly object Instance;

        public JavaHolder(object instance)
        {
            Instance = instance;
        }


    }

    public static class ObjectExtensions
    {
        public static TObject ToNetObject<TObject>(this Java.Lang.Object value)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return default(TObject);

            if (!(value is JavaHolder))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to convert to .NET object. Only Java.Lang.Object created with .ToJavaObject() can be converted.");

            TObject returnVal;
            try { returnVal = (TObject)((JavaHolder)value).Instance; }
            finally { value.Dispose(); }
            return returnVal;
        }

        public static Java.Lang.Object ToJavaObject<TObject>(this TObject value)
        {
            if (Equals(value, default(TObject)) && !typeof(TObject).IsValueType)
                return null;

            var holder = new JavaHolder(value);

            return holder;
        }
    }
}
```

my main activity:

```
 List<Rsultitem> tableItems = new List<Rsultitem>();
        ListView lst;
        homeadapter hm;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            string info = "More Info";
            lst = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.List);
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                //tableItems.Add(new Rsultitem() { itembarcode = itmcode[i], name = itmname[i], itemsunitcode= itmunit[i], currentQuantity=itmQty[i],moreInfo=info});

                tableItems.Add(new Rsultitem() { itembarcode = "fff", name = "jhhh", itemsunitcode = "jjj", currentQuantity = "uy", moreInfo = info });
            }
            hm = new homeadapter(this, tableItems);
            lst.Adapter=hm;
            SearchView searchView1 = FindViewById<SearchView>(Resource.Id.searchView1);
            searchView1.QueryTextChange += (s, e) => hm.Filter.InvokeFilter(e.NewText);

            searchView1.QueryTextSubmit += (s, e) =>
            {
                // Handle enter/search button on keyboard here
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Searched for: " + e.Query, ToastLength.Short).Show();
                e.Handled = true;
            };


}
private class SearchViewExpandListener : Java.Lang.Object, MenuItemCompat.IOnActionExpandListener
        {
            private readonly IFilterable _adapter;

            public SearchViewExpandListener(IFilterable adapter)
            {
                _adapter = adapter;
            }

            public bool OnMenuItemActionCollapse(IMenuItem item)
            {
                _adapter.Filter.InvokeFilter("");
                return true;
            }

            public bool OnMenuItemActionExpand(IMenuItem item)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

but the problem is that nothing happened. I only got the toast telling what is written in the search view upon submitting. no filtering happened. I so sorry for the long post. could anyone help me find the problem. thanks in advance.

Comment: I test your codes ,it works well,it could filter what you entry in the searchview.Could you provide a recording screen to describe your issue?

Comment: thanks a lot sir, i was working on it and figured out that I was missing a class. thanks a lot